# How to replace multiple words in a string through Python in a case insensitive way?

Tags: python, regex, django, string, replace

Lets say for example, I have the string:

```
s = 'Back in BLACK, I hit the sAck, I've been too LOng I'm glad to be back.'
```

In the above string, I want to search & replace certain words in a case insensitive way with the following words

black : b***

sack : s***

long : l***

glad : g***

I would like the resulting string to be

```
s = 'Back in B****, I hit the s***, I've been too L*** I'm glad to be back.'
```

Basically the above string maintains the case of the first letter of the word I am replacing. The letters after the word will trail with '***'

I'm assuming I would need to make a list of some sort with the replacements. In Django I am currently using the replace_all() function but it's case sensitive. So for words like BLACK and sAck, this becomes a daunting task since there are many combinations!

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Can you show the exact output you expect?

Comment: I think ACDC would want to know what you have tried. Please edit your question with your latest and greatest attempt, and folks will point in you in the right direction.

Comment: s = 'Back in B***, I hit the s***, I've been too L*** I;m glad to be back'.

Comment: @bernie I edited my question, hopefully I am more clear this time. F.J. gave me a really good example, but in the case where I want to replace different words all at once, how can I go about doing that?

Comment: Two of the very best are helping you now, so I won't jump in and muddy the waters. Thank you for editing your question with your attempt. Your edit makes this a far better question in my opinion.

Comment: @bernie, thank you for the suggestion, you helped me get in the right direction, appreciate it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [re module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), here is a brief example for "black":

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Back in BLACK, I hit the sAck, I've been too LOng I'm glad to be back."
>>> regex = re.compile(r'black', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
>>> regex.sub('b***', s)
"Back in b***, I hit the sAck, I've been too LOng I'm glad to be back."
```

To keep the case of the first letter, capture it and use a back reference in the replacement:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r'(b)lack', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
>>> regex.sub(r'\1***', s)
"Back in B***, I hit the sAck, I've been too LOng I'm glad to be back."
```

To do all the replacements in one pass:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r'(?=(.))(?:black|sack|long|glad)', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
>>> regex.sub(r'\1***', s)
"Back in B***, I hit the s***, I've been too L*** I'm g*** to be back."
```

Comment: How can I use it for multiple words such as sack and LOng and glad?

Comment: the problem I'm running into @F.J is that I don't know how I can use for multiple words that I want to replace :(

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit dense, but works:

```
>>> re.sub(
        r"(?i)\b(black|sack|long|glad)\b", 
        lambda m: m.group()[0] + "*"*(len(m.group())-1), 
        s
        )
"Back in B****, I hit the s***, I've been too L*** I'm g*** to be back."
```

Comment: Thank for the answer as well @Ned Batchelder!